# How to configure ClamAV autoupdate

Tags: django, antivirus, clamav

I am using ClamAV for scanning our files in our Django application. I am running `freshclam` manually to update the antivirus database. My question is how to automate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ClamAV [documentation](https://www.clamav.net/documents/configuration#freshclamconf), I created a Cron job with the following code:-

```
N * * * *   /usr/local/bin/freshclam --quiet
```